# flex-flow : column isn't wroking

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to order items by column
It works very well at 'flex : row wrap'
but  'flex-flow : column wrap '
doesn't work.. also I tried 'flex-direction : column and flex-wrap : wrap '

I can't found any error at my code
please help..

```css
* {
  font-size: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;

  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 3% auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.wrap div {
  color: yellow;
  width: 33.333333333333%;
}
.wrap div:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
}
.wrap div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
.wrap div:last-child {
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is expected output you need?

Comment: three colors in a row  like french flags?

Comment: if I am using column wrap it is giving me output. Only issue is that it is not taking entire width. Let me know are you looking for something related with width issue.

Comment: you have to provide height to div to work in column wrap to see output.

Comment: i find answer if i using colum  i should give height  :D thank so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what you want. You need to use `flex-grow` for each item so that they grow to take all the space of the container.

```css
* {
  font-size: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;

  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 3% auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.wrap div {
  color: yellow;
  width: 33.333333333333%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.wrap div:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
}
.wrap div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
.wrap div:last-child {
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Edit*** : If you don't have any content in the divs then wrapping will not work if you use the above method. To enable wrapping, you will have to provide custom height to the items like in the snippet below:

```css
* {
  font-size: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;

  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 3% auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.wrap div {
  color: yellow;
  width: 33.333333333333%;
  height: 150px;
}
.wrap div:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
}
.wrap div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
.wrap div:last-child {
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```